# Issues creating CNAME for blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

For the last two days I've been unable to create a CNAME from my domain to my blob storage account. I've registered the domain and added a CNAME that points to verify.azure.com on my DNS settings, but whenever I validate it (even after waiting a few hours), it never seems to validate... the error I get the Azure portal is "An unexpected error occurred while validating the domain name. Try again later."

Are there some issues going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verify.azure.com will only authenticate that you have the proper key to your domain however you would need another alias to set the proper CNAME configuration. Based on what you have written above you are pointing your host to verify.azure.com, however have you setup your storage subdomain alias to your storage name as well? If you have setup both the entries correctly, and still see the problem, at your domain registrar level there are some logs available which you can request for further troubleshooting.

Get more info [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/#header-2) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/22/using-custom-domain-name-with-windows-azure-storage-instead-of-windows-stroage-name-blob-core-windows-net.aspx).

Comment: No idea what "fixed" this, but I deleted the storage account and created a new one, then the verification worked. Go figure...